# Create a searchable select box in Cordova

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a select drop-down with a long list of options in my Cordova Android app. Is there any component/plugin that I can use to create a searchable select box, that includes a search text box in the select popup in which user can type a search text string and only the matching options can be shown to the user to select from.

This would avoid the user having to scroll through the long list in the select options.

Comment: select2/jquery ui ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Android, I added the js file and set the class of the select box to `select2` but it does show any search box in the select popup in the Android Emulator.

Comment: any javascript errors?

Comment: No, don't get any JS errors. I have added `$('select2box').select2();` in my js file and `<select id="mySelect" class="select2box"></select> ` and data is being populated at runtime using AJAX `$.get()`

Comment: Is there any other option/issue?